# how to scroll modal window in imacros (slack.com)?

Tags: imacros, slack

I have the task: get all names members of (myworkspace).slack.com/messages/****/details/ in #general channel.

On this page I click "Members" -> "See all members". 
Modal window appears, and Imacros has to scroll this modal window while all members not visible.

(js) But this code dont work:

```
var modal = window.content.document.getElementById("generic_dialog");  // Modal window with all members
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=javascript:modal.scrollBy(0, 1000)"); // Scrolling
```

Comment: Why try to grab data from the browser window, when you can use the API? e.g. [conversations.members](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members) to get members of any channel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody prefers using a bookmarklet to scroll that list:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var scrInt = setInterval(() => {try {document.querySelector("#channel_membership_dialog_scroller").scrollTop += 5000} catch(e) {clearInterval(scrInt)}}, 1500);
})();
```